# Outlook Plugin create Outlook Teams Meeting

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am programming an outlook plugin for outlook desktop app. I already create appointments

As we have installed [Teams](https://products.office.com/de-at/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software), some of the appointments should be teams appointments. By hand this can be done as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/schedule-a-teams-meeting-from-outlook-883cc15c-580f-441a-92ea-0992c00a9b0f). I want to do it programatically. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run the command on the ribbon programmatically. You just need to know the `idMso` value of the built-in command. The `ExecuteMso` method of the CoommandBars class is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`. On failure, it returns `E_InvalidArg` for an invalid `idMso`, and `E_Fail` for controls that are not enabled or not visible.

But we deal with an add-in, so their `idMso` values are not disclosed. In that case your option is to use Accessibility API, see [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) for more information. Microsoft Active Accessibility is a Component Object Model (COM)-based technology that improves the way accessibility aids work with applications running on Microsoft Windows. It provides dynamic-link libraries that are incorporated into the operating system as well as a COM interface and API elements that provide reliable methods for exposing information about UI elements.

As the last resort, you may consider using Windows API function to click the button programmatically.